# test form is vaild with valid data without posting data django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-testing, django-tests

I want to ask a question, is there any possible to test form is valid with post data, which means it can generate dictionary of data automatically according to form. because I have a lot of form to test. I dont want to write data = {'A':'a', 'B':'b'}, too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

[factory boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will probably help, especially the `faker` objects